# How to achive round corners on standart android button (@android:style/Widget.Button.Small)

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, rounding, rounded-corners

I know shapes and stuff but issue is that I want to use standart android button from SDK (@android:style/Widget.Button.Small) Just have a look at screenshot. I know how to do round corners with "shape" then "solid" which is flat color but i want .png from library ...

[image]

Card doesn't work...
Nope even with "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton" doesn't work ...
[image]

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        style="@style/gtBtnMenuStyle">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_supervisor_48dp"
            android:onClick="onSupervisorClick"
            android:text="Supervisor"
            style="@style/gtBtnMenuStyle"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Or if you know any gradient stuff with shadows to mimick the original btn ...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to take any drawable then one solution is to try to add a button into the **cardview**

Please find below code:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40sdp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"/>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.

Comment: what problem generated?

Comment: Sorry that was missing "androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton"... still didnt get the result yet

Comment: add style into the button as per my answer

Comment: if you want same design then why use button and set drawable?Take main linear layout into card view and set image and text.

Comment: Also add height and width of button.Why are you not add I am not understand?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206273/discussion-between-ion-iascerinschi-and-hardik-talaviya).

Comment: Set your button background into cardview